# The Requested Database is not defined in the configuration

Tags: c#, .net

An application I am working on is using Microsoft Practices Enterprise to handle database interactions.

This was all fine and good, however at some point it simply stopped working. The only thing I can think of is that I restored the database I was working on from another database deployed on a different machine (accessed by a user(s) with different accounts than the one I am using now).

I have created 2 small tests (1 solution with 1 project having 1 class, `Program.cs`), the first works:

```
        static void test1()
        {
            // Create a connection
            SqlConnection sdwDBConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString());

            // Open the connection
            sdwDBConnection.Open();

            // Create a String to hold the query.
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Test1]";

            // Create a SqlCommand object and pass the constructor the connection string and the query string.
            SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sdwDBConnection);

            // Use the above SqlCommand object to create a SqlDataReader object.
            SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();

            // Create a DataTable object to hold all the data returned by the query.
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            // Use the DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader) function to put the results of the query into a DataTable.
            dataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);

            // Example 1 - Print your  Column Headers
            String columns = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                columns += column.ColumnName + " | ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(columns);

            // Close the connection
            sdwDBConnection.Close();
            System.Console.Read();
        }
```

Yielding:

> ID1 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |

However the second one fails:

```
        static void test2()
        {
            try
            {
                Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Test");    //Line 59
                using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT * FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[Test1]"))
                {
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", reader.GetInt64(0)      
                            , reader.GetString(1) 
                            , reader.GetString(2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Console.Read();
            }
        }
```

Yielding:

```
The requested database Test is not defined in configuration.
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer
 lifetimeContainer, String id, IConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](String id, IConfigurationSource configuration
Source)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(String name)
   at ....Program.test2() in ...\Program.cs:line 59
```

This is my `app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />    
  </configSections>  
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Test" />
  <connectionStrings>       
  <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI; Connect Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>  
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I *think* that if there where any connection/configuration issue the first one would fail as well. I have tried using the empty constructor as well, but that just throws another exception saying that the `String` parameter must not be `null` or empty.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: From doc : "DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(string) Method for invoking a specified Database service object. Reads service settings from the ConnectionSettings.config file." 
I never heard about a ConnectionSettings.config, but did you try to create a ConnectionSettings.config ?

Comment: @JoffreyKern Not really. I never heard of it either and wanted to see if there was something I broke rather than trying to add something to try and go round the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a *conflict* between Microsoft products. In my case, it was the ESB Toolkit installation. More information is available [here](http://gloriousmonster.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/esb-toolkit-20-has-surprise-for.html).

Uninstalling the ESB Toolkit was in my case, the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you using

```
Database sda = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DBConnectionString");
```

Make sure you have this setting in `App.config`

```
"connectionStrings
    add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="server=DBServerNameHere;database=DatabaseNameHere;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  connectionStrings"
```